# What is an RKO in wrestling?

Tags: terminology, pro-wrestling

I'm not much of a wrestling fan, but I often hear about a RKO.

I know KO (Knock Out) and TKO (Technical Knock Out, where it's not a KO in itself, but the fight is considered one).

What is an RKO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An "RKO" is [Randy Orton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randy_Orton)'s finishing maneuver (named after his initials), a variation of the "[Jumping Cutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutter_(professional_wrestling)#Jumping_cutter)." This is not a "technical" wrestling term like KO or TKO.

[image: RKO]

This was popularized in pop culture through Vines known as "RKO Outta Nowhere."

- https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/early-lead/wp/2014/10/19/rko-out-of-nowhere-meme-is-everywhere-including-this-awesome-goal-celebration/?utm_term=.ea5255ea9cfb
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qz-rsqEaa_s